# Angularjs How to communicate between two modals

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am trying to do here is:

Type in the new language name and click "Add" button, the new language will be added into the existing object.

For example: the existing object: {"default": "English"}, When I type in "German", a new object is added like this: {"default": "English", "German": "German"}

Here is my [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/oStaQg?p=preview).

Could someone help me on that? Thanks so much, I will appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use events. Just subscribe one piece on some event like:

```
$rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(event, info){
// do something
});
```

And another one will fire it:

```
scope.$broadcast('myEvent', info);
```

The system glitched when I was trying to save your plunkr or I don't have a permission so here the code:

```
        var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.factory('Data', function(){
      var data = 
        {
          Language: ''
        };

      return {
        setLanguage: function(language) {
          data.Language = language;
        }
      }
    })

    var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {


      $scope.languages = {"sch": "Simple Chinese"};
      $scope.$on('newLanguageAdded', function(e, lang){
           $scope.languages[lang] = lang;

     });

      $scope.open = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
          resolve: {
            languages: function () {
              return $scope.languages;
            },
            newLanguage: function () {
              return $scope.newLanguage;
            }
          }
        });

      };
    };

    // Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
    // It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

    var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $modalInstance, languages, newLanguage) {

      $scope.languages = languages;

      $scope.ok = function () {

        $modalInstance.close($scope.languages);

      };

      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };

      $scope.openDialog = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'addNewLanguageDialog.html',
          controller: AddNewLanguageCtrl,
        });
      }

    var AddNewLanguageCtrl = function ($scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance, Data){
        $scope.newValue = {text: ''};

        $scope.$watch('newLanguage', function(newValue) {
          if(newValue) Data.setLanguage(newValue);
        }); 

        $scope.add = function () {
          alert($scope.newValue.text);
          $rootScope.$broadcast('newLanguageAdded', $scope.newValue.text);
          $modalInstance.close($scope.languages);  
        }

        $scope.cancel = function () {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');  
        }
      }




    };
```

You can just copy this piece into plunkr instead yours.
Also change the layout:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <input ng-model="newValue.text">
        </div>
```

Let me know if something doesn't work

Comment: hi, i am not quite understand, could you update the plunker and show me the code?

Comment: thanks! it looks nice! is it possible to make the language as an object, rather than an array

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a service, by definition singletons, and inject it in both models, adding a watch to the array in the service and updating accordingly in the scope of every model, from the values in the service.

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you give me an example on that? thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers here is an example

Comment: hi, could you help me to check again, I updated the service, but still have some problem

Answer (score 1):

An angular-ui way to achieve what you need would be to use these two basic methodologies found in the angular-ui documentation. See associated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VXIFkD?p=preview) for the answer below.

First is to use the `close(result)` inside the Instance Controller of the modal which updates the `result` promise property of the Instance Controller

Second is to use the `result` promise property to get the result(s) passed on to the `close()` method

**Inside The AddNewLanguageCtrl** is something like this

```
$scope.data = {newLanguage: ""};

$scope.add = function() {
  $scope.close(data.newLanguage);
};
```

Inside the your `addNewLanguageDialog.html` script template
instead of using

```
<input ng-model="newLanguage">
```

use this

```
<input ng-model="data.newLanguage">
```

This is because whenever a modal is created, a new scope is created under the $rootScope(default) if a scope is not passed on to the options when the $modal.open() is invoked as stated in the [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) documentation. If you use `newLanguage` as the model then it won't receive any updates inside the `AddNewLanguageCtrl`. You can [read this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) to get a better understanding of what I'm talking about regarding scopes

**Inside the first modal ModalInstanceCtrl** is something like this

```
  $scope.newLanguages = [];

  $scope.openDialog = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'addNewLanguageDialog.html',
      controller: AddNewLanguageCtrl,
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(newLanguage) {
      if(newLanguage)
        $scope.newLanguages.push(newLanguage);
    });

  };
```

**And then in your ModalDemoCtrl**

```
$scope.languages = [];

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(languages) {
        $scope.languages = $scope.languages.concat(languages);
    });

  };
```